# Referencia cruzada o pivote realizando consulta a dos tablas mediante inner join y organizar los datos en una sola fila

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Tengo dos tablas de la base de datos:

Tabla **familia**:

| id_familia | apellido_familia |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | WICK FOO |
| 2 | CENA JHONNSON |

Tabla **persona**:

| id_persona | id_familia | nombre |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | JHON |
| 2 | 1 | MARIA |
| 3 | 2 | RUBENS |
| 4 | 2 | LUZ |
| 5 | 2 | JOSHEP |

Es claro que cuando hago una consulta media **INNER JOIN** a la base de datos el resultado sea de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT f.id_familia,f.apellido_familia,p.nombre 
FROM familia AS f 
INNER JOIN persona AS p 
ON f.id_familia = p.id_familia;
```

| id_familia | familia | nombre |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | WICK FOO | JHON |
| 1 | WICK FOO | MARIA |
| 2 | CENA JHONNSON | RUBENS |
| 2 | CENA JHONNSON | LUZ |
| 2 | CENA JHONNSON | JOSHEP |

Entiendo que ese es el resultado esperado realizado a la base de datos, pero no es lo que yo deseo. Me gustaría generar una consulta a la base de datos mediante **pivot** o **referencia cruzada** si ese es el caso o sea algún método distinto mediante el cual el resultado esperado sea:

| id_familia | familia | nombre_1 | nombre_2 | nombre_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | WICK FOO | JHON | MARIA |  |
| 2 | CENA JHONNSON | RUBENS | LUZ | JOSHEP |

Comment: No mayusc en titulo pls

Comment: Por favor, agregá en las etiquetas a qué motor de base de datos hacés referencia (MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL-Server, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Usualmente, esto es algo que se deja para la capa de visualización, debido a que es más sencillo tener un número dinámico de columnas.

Para poder organizarlos en columnas, tenemos que asignar números a cada fila para poder identificarlas y poder transponerlas. Esto se hace con la función ROW_NUMBER(). Después de eso, es sencillo organizarlas usando funciones de agregado condicionales.

```
SELECT fp.id_familia,
       fp.apellido_familia AS familia,
       MAX( CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN fp.nombre END) AS nombre_1,
       MAX( CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN fp.nombre END) AS nombre_2,
       MAX( CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN fp.nombre END) AS nombre_3
FROM( 
    SELECT f.id_familia,
           f.apellido_familia,
           p.nombre,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY f.id_familia ORDER BY p.nombre) rn
    FROM familia AS f 
    INNER JOIN persona AS p ON f.id_familia = p.id_familia) fp
GROUP BY fp.id_familia,
       fp.apellido_familia;
```

Comment: ¿ que pasaría en caso que  la seleccion de personas sea dinámica? es decir en lugar de colocar nombre_1, nombre_2, nombre_3.  muestre la información de personas de  forma dinamica ya que se da el caso que hay mas de 3 personas que son parte de la familia y colocarlo de manera estatica entraria en problema porque solo se estaria mostrando la informacion de de esas 3 personas pertenecientes a una familia y eso sería un problema.

Comment: Para hacerlo dinámico, es necesario que indiques el manejador de base de datos que estás usando, ya que eso implica instrucciones específicas de cada lenguaje. El nombre de las columnas no puede ser dinámico en este caso, porque el nombre cambia entre una fila y otra.

Comment: En este caso seria Microsoft SQL Server.